# Can I convert a PDF to text if it has a rotated table?

Tags: pdf, document-converter

I've been using the tool [`ps2txt`](https://gist.github.com/btbytes/f0cc557efe2b18df21be), however it doesn't seem to work if it has a rotated table (rendered linearlly) . Is there anything that can extract text from a rotated table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I could find to do what I want is `pdftotext` with `-layout`.

- http://poppler.freedesktop.org